# Relationship with list and dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object

I am learning python through "*Learn Python The Hard Way*" by *Zed A Shaw*.

I am currently confused by this question

> Make some new relationships that are lists and dictionaries so you can also have "has-many" relationships.

Can anyone explain and give me some examples?

**EDIT**
This is the link
[Exercise 42](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex42.html)

Comment: It would really help us help you, if you could post a link to where we would find that quote

Comment: Usually dictionaries can represent a "relationship", where a `key` maps to a `value`. A "has-many" relationship could work if a `dictionary` has one or more `keys` that each map to a `list` that contains multiple `values`.

Comment: –1  just for using LPTHW

Comment: @wim Even though you have ridiculously high rep, I don't think disliking the teaching material is a valid reason to downvote the question (even if it's just a joke).

Comment: @wim Well perhaps instead of just downvoting, you could explain why you dislike LPTHW as a teaching material. I do agree that there are much better books than LPTHW, but it doesn't really help the OP to just downvote.

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book. Also be aware that Python 2 will reach its End Of Life in 2020, so you really ought to be learning Python 3, unless you need Python 2 to work on legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

A [*has-many*](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasMany-relations.html) relationship *X* to *Y* usually means that every element in *X* is associated with many (zero or more) elements in *Y*. So you can construct a **dictionary that maps elements of *X* to a *list* of *Y***.

For instance if we want to know what a person (*X*) owns (*Y*):

```
{
 'Alice': ['laptop','house'],
 'Bob':['Gameboy'],
 'Chris':['pony'],
 'Plankton':[]
}
```

So here (1) Alice owns a laptop and a house. (2) Bob owns only a gameboy and (3) Chris owns a pony and (4) Plankton owns nothing at all.

Comment: _"Chris owns nothing at all."_ - Poor me :-(

Comment: @ChristianDean: I gave you a pony. Happy? :)

Comment: [I'd prefer a unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow), but pony will do :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sure; I've taught programming including this material.  You have each dictionary entry contain a *list* of values, instead of just the one one.  For instance:

```
 Children = 
    {"Marianne": ["Eduardo", "Shibani", "Ted",
     "Stephan":  ["Marianne"],
     "Ted":      ["Winken", "Blinken", "Nod"]
    }
```

This is a simple list of parents, giving the children of each.  In this case, you can also write code to see part of a family tree: Stephan is grandfather to Ted and two other children.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does "this material" refer to "one-to-many correspondence" or "learn python the hard way"?

Comment: It's "one-to-many": the parents (dict keys) are the "one"; the children (dict values, as lists), are the "many".

Answer (score 1):

to contextualize:
in exercise 42 of the book Learn Python The Hard Way we are studing about classes and objects.
The autor Zed Shaw give us the code below and we have to make comments for the classes and objects.
We have to use "is-a" when we talk about objects and classes being related to each other by a class relationship. We use 'has-a' when we talk about objects and classes that are related only because they "reference" each other.

So, the code with my comments:

```
## Animal is-a object
class Animal(object):
    pass

## Dog is-a Animal
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self,name):
        ## Dog has-a name
        self.name = name

## Cat is-a Animal
class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name):
        ## Cat has-a name
        self.name = name

## Person is-a object
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        ## Person has-a name
        self.name = name

        ## Person has-a pet of some kind
        self.pet = None

## Employee is-a Person
class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        ## Employee has-a name (coming from Person, because Employee is-a Person)
        super(Employee, self).__init__(name)
        ## Employee has-a salary
        self.salary = salary

## Fish is-a object
class Fish(object):
    pass

## Salmon is-a Fish
class Salmon(Fish):
    pass

## Kalibut is-a Fish:
class Halibut(Fish):
    pass


## Rover is-a Dog
rover = Dog("Rover")

## Satan is-a Cat
satan = Cat("Satan")

## Mary is-a Person
mary = Person("Mary")

## Mary has-a pet "Satan"
mary.pet = satan

# Frank is-a Employee that has-a salary
frank = Employee("Frank", 120000)

## Frank has-a pet "Rover"
frank.pet = rover

## flipper is-a fish
flipper = Fish()

## crouse is-a Salmon
crouse = Salmon()

## harry is-a Halibut
harry = Halibut
```

In one of the study drills the autor tell to us "Make some new relationships that are lists and dictionaries so you can also have “has-many” relationships."

So, for exemple:

```
## Mary is-a Person
mary = Person("Mary")

## Mary has-a pet "Santan"
mary.pet = santan
```

But Mary can have more than one pet, right? So:

```
## Mary has-many pets: "Santan" and "Rover"
mary.pet = [santan, rover]  # has-many with list
```

Or, you can use a dictionary, so:

```
## Mary has-many pets: Satan (is-a cat) and rover (is a dog)
mary.pet =  {'cat': satan, 'dog': rover}  # has-many with dictionary
```

Now everyone can understand the context of the question.

Comment: *"for the people who are reading the book, maybe it will be easier to understand"*
Perhaps include a bit more so that people aren't lost? What are `santan` and `rover`?

Comment: What you think about now? I try to give a good context, showing what the book gives us and what it asks of us.

Comment: Yes much clearer! So the code is taken from the source as is, you just added the comments? I have to say it looks weird. If we follow it, a Fish is not an animal and therefor cannot have a name ^^'...

Comment: Yes, the code was given to us, and we just add the comments. I don't think the code wants to be functional, maybe the autor just want to treining us to know that a class with (object) is a normal thing in python's code. But of course, Fish can be a Animal and therefor have a name.